# R not recognizing that 7zip is installed

Tags: r, 7zip

I'm working in R using the package `nhdR` ([link to package page](https://github.com/jsta/nhdR)).

`nhdR` requires `7zip` to unzip data downloaded with package functions (e.g. `nhd_plus_get()`). I'm on a MacBook pro, so I installed 7zip through the terminal via homebrew (`brew install p7zip`). This seems to have worked fine.

However, when I call `nhdR` functions that require `7zip`, R appears not to recognize that I have `7zip` installed. And as far as I can tell, there's no additional step needed to configure R to use `7zip`. Any idea what's happening? Is there some path I need to specify in R to the location of `7zip`? I'm losing it a bit with this, so any help is appreciated.

What I've run:

*Terminal:*

```
brew install p7zip

7z

7-Zip [64] 17.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28
p7zip Version 17.04 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs LE)

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
```

(and also returns a list of commands and switches)

*RStudio:*

```
nhdR::nhd_plus_get(vpu = 15, component = "NHDSnapshot")
```

which returns

```
Error in nhd_plus_get(vpu = 15, component = "NHDSnapshot") : 
  The 7-zip program is needed to unpack NHD downloads (http://www.7-zip.org/).
```

digging further,

```
nhdR:::has_7z()

$yes
[1] FALSE

$path
[1] NA
```

Session info:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

(plus lots of packages)

Comment: `Sys.which("7z")` returns what? The configuration for R to find it has nothing to do with R: update your `PATH` environment variable in your operating system. If you've done that, know that you must also either restart R from a new login session (so that it sees the new/updated envvar) or manually update it for now with `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/new/path", sep = .Platform$path.sep)`.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! For some odd reason, `Sys.getenv("PATH")` in R returns a different path than `printenv PATH` in terminal. So I've added the `Sys.setenv()` call to my .Rprofile. This problem came up as I set up a new MacBook pro with Apple chips (first time I haven't had Intel) - I wonder if that's contributing to the wackiness? Idle speculation, as this is not remotely my expertise at all. Thanks again for helping a relative novice figure this out!